# How to check (count) are returned data?

Tags: python, peewee, flask-peewee

I have got this query in Peewee:

```
return c = Products.get(Products.sku == article).get()
```

How to check if it returns data?

I tried:

```
if c.count() > 0:

if len(c) > 0
```

It does not work for me

This is full code:

```
try:
    r = self.isProductExist(row['sku'])

    ## if (r.count() == 0):

except peewee.DoesNotExist:

   # Insert product


    def isProductExist(self, article):
      return Products.get(Products.sku == article).get()
```

Comment: `return c = Products.get(Products.sku == article).get()` is not valid code. Just do `c = Products.get(Products.sku == article).get()`. Can you elaborate on how you know it doesn't work? Does it give you an error?

Comment: I put this query in try: `except peewee.DoesNotExist:`

Comment: update your question with the code

Comment: @Gundama I'm sorry, I don't think I understand your issue. If you provide more of your code i'm sure someone here can help.

Comment: Done, see question

Comment: Wow man, do you even know how to write Python? This is nonsensical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is all kinds of wrong.

First of all, the 2nd call to "get()" is not necessary here:

```
return c = Products.get(Products.sku == article).get()
```

Second of all, you are returning an assignment (?) which makes no sense. Change to:

```
 return Products.get(Products.sku == article)
```

If the product exists, it will be returned. If not, a DoesNotExist exception will be raised, making it unnecessary to call "count()" anywhere.

To make the code work even if the product is not found:

```
try:
    return Products.get(Products.sku == article)
except Products.DoesNotExist:
    # Product was not found.
    return
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `count()`.

Here is a working code:

```python
import peewee
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('/tmp/a.db')

class Products(Model):
    sku = CharField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

db.connect()
db.drop_tables(models=[Products], safe=True)
db.create_tables([Products])


count = Products.select().count()
print(count) #=> 0
if not count:
    Products.create(sku="abc")

print(Products.select().count()) #=> 1

print(peewee.__version__) #=> 3.0.18
```

Comment: count() has been around for a long time, it is not specific to 3.x.

Comment: @coleifer thanks, fixed.  any other mistake you see?

Comment: Nope, looks fine.